# Nullable type as a generic parameter

Tags: c#

I'm trying to implement a class that stores a generic nullable type:

```
public class myclass<T?>
{
    T? myvariable;

    public T? myfunction(){
        return myvariable;
    }
 }
```

And while the above class compiles just fine, the actual use that provides trouble:

```
myclass<int?> c = new myclass<int>();
int? = c.myfunction();   // does not work: implicit cast from type T? in int? not possible.
// or, assuming the variable is not null
int = c.myfunction().Value; // implicit cast from type T in int not possible.
```

What am I doing wrong or how can I work around this?

Comment: And your example doesn't make sense. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Indeed it does not compile ... sorry, an other error must have covered it in the syntax checker.

What I am tying to achive is a class that stores a nullable type. (What is missing from the above example is the part where the variable is set)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither of the examples compile:

- `<T?>` isn't valid syntax; it should be `<T>`
- [`myclass` needs a `where T : struct` constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fsdhc71f.aspx)
- The first line of your second example should read: `myclass<int> c = new myclass<int>();`.

The rest of your second example should compile OK, however.